# Read from url and write to Tempfile

Tags: ruby, temporary-files

Say I have this url: [Image](http://s3.amazonaws.com/estock/fspid10/27/40/27/6/buddhism-hindu-religion-2740276-o.png)

And I want to write its contents to a tempfile. I am doing it like this:

```
url =  http://s3.amazonaws.com/estock/fspid10/27/40/27/6/buddhism-hindu-religion-2740276-o.png
tmp_file = Tempfile.new(['chunky_image', '.png'])
tmp_file.binmode

open(url) do |url_file|
  tmp_file.write(url_file.read)
end
```

But it seems tmp_file is empty. Beacuse when I do:

```
tmp_file.read => # ""
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just do as

```
open(url) do |url_file|
  tmp_file.write(url_file.read)
end

tmp_file.rewind

tmp_file.read
```

Look at the [documentation example](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/tempfile/rdoc/Tempfile.html#class-Tempfile-label-Synopsis).

The problem in your case was that you were doing a *read* at the current `IO` pointer in the `temp_file`, that is already at the end when you completed with *writes*. Thus you need to do a `rewind` before the `read`.

Comment: It's worth noting that `read` reads from the current offset in the file, which after having written to it is the end. `rewind` goes back to the beginning.

Answer (score 6):

You need `tmp_file.rewind`

```
url = "http://s3.amazonaws.com/estock/fspid10/27/40/27/6/buddhism-hindu-religion-2740276-o.png"
tmp_file = Tempfile.new(['chunky_image', '.png'])
tmp_file.binmode

open(url) do |url_file|
  tmp_file.write(url_file.read)
end

#You need to bring the cursor back to the start of the file with:

tmp_file.rewind

tmp_file.read
```